# Remove rows with NAs from a dataframe which contains columns with ids

Tags: r

From a dataframe like:

```
DF <- data.frame(ids = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA), z=c(NA, 33, 22))
```

it is possible to remove rows which contains an NA using this:

```
completeFun <- function(data, desiredCols) {
  completeVec <- complete.cases(data[, desiredCols])
  return(data[completeVec, ])
}

completeFun(DF, "y")
#   x  y  z
# 1 1  0 NA
# 2 2 10 33

completeFun(DF, c("y", "z"))
```

How is it possible to remove rows which contains in all cells NA and not remove every rows which contains one NA.

Example of input:

```
DF <- data.frame(ids = c(1, 2, 3,4), y = c(0, 10, NA,NA), z=c(NA, 33, 22,NA))
```

Example of expected output:

```
DF <- data.frame(ids = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA), z=c(NA, 33, 22))
```

Comment: Use `rowSums` to create the logical vector i.e. `DF[rowSums(is.na(DF[-1])) < 2,]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
solution <- DF[!(rowSums(is.na(DF)) == NCOL(DF)-1),]
```

This should work for any number of columns, assuming there is always a ID-column which is guaranteed to not contain any NAs.

Input:

```
> DF
  ids  y  z
1   1  0 NA
2   2 10 33
3   3 NA 22
4   4 NA NA
```

Output:

```
> solution
  ids  y  z
1   1  0 NA
2   2 10 33
3   3 NA 22
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also combine `all()` and `is.na()`. Try

```
all.na <- apply(DF[-1], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))) # DF[-1] doesn't select column "ids"
DF[!all.na, ]
```